# How can I add HTTPS to my running Tor webserver

Tags: configuration, website, https

I've got a local running server and I want to add HTTPS to the requests instead of HTTP, that's it. I've seen the posts on Tor (like https://kushaldas.in/posts/get-a-tls-certificate-for-your-onion-service.html) but I want a free certificate, it can be a self-signed certificate, I want to know how to do it
I appreciate any help you can provide, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-signed is the only option if we're speaking about security! But you can make it even more secure ;)

- First of all, make the DH params `openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 4096`
- Second - you need the certificate itself `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`
- Third - propagate the public key on blockchain DNS like that https://emercoin.com/en/documentation/blockchain-services/emerssl/emerssl-guide/

Comment: That is what I was thinking. I get the unsafe website warning but the only option to not display that is to create a certificate based on a trusted CA and for that, I need to pay right?

Comment: For getting rid of the warning - yes, but should you? If you're having an onion-only resource, then don't pay. If you want to make a mixed site - make a CSR and send it to the paid CA, **never** use their one-pager where they will do everything for you and just send you the files